# Standard C++ data structure with multiple "indexes"

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, c++11

Is there standard structure or library in C++ (or C++11) that is something like like a `set`, but that could have more than one `key`.

i.e. a set of std::pair that can be looked up fast by either `a` or `b`.

So you could do something like this:

```
std::string a = "hello";
std::string b = "world";

x.insert(a, b);

x.get<1>("hello") => std::pair("hello", "world"); // (fast lookup)
x.get<2>("world") => std::pair("hello", "world"); // (fast lookup)
```

Basically like a database table with two indexes.

I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if something already exists.

A simple way to combine existing containers to make something with this functionality would be good also.

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450095/maintaining-a-unique-set-of-elements-on-different-criteria-c-stl/4450256#4450256

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what your definition of "standard C++" is, but [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) works with any standard C++ compiler.