# C++ std:sort() using different criteria

Tags: c++, stl, function-object

I searched a lot and I am not sure if this is query is repeated but I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4450095/1410711) as an reference to create a sort for my `std::vector` which takes data of following type.

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int type;
    int id;
} AC;
```

I was able to  write individual function objects for each criteria.
However, my project requirement says that I need to have only once class or struct to include all the function objects for sorting according to `size`,`type` and `id`. Is it possible to have all the function objects for `std::sort` in one class?

I mean something like

```
Comparator com;
sort(iVec.begin(),iVec.end(),com.sortbysize);
sort(iVec.begin(),iVec.end(),com.sortbytype);
sort(iVec.begin(),iVec.end(),com.sortbyid);
```

I also looked at `binary_functions` to fulfill my requirement but I was getting errors, when I declared more than one function object in a single class.

Further, is it necessary that function objects for `std::sort` (and for that matter any STL algorithm which involves comparison) need to be `bool operator()` or they can be normal functions returning `bool`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes to both:

```
struct Comparator
{
    static bool sortbysize(const AC &lhs, const AC &rhs) { /*...*/ }
    static bool sortbytype(const AC &lhs, const AC &rhs) { /*...*/ }
    static bool sortbyid(const AC &lhs, const AC &rhs) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Comment: @JesseGood, the original answer was too short: 
1. Yes. 
2. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to have a class, you can define static functions on it:

```
class MyComparator {
    public:
        static bool sortbysize( const AC & elem1, const AC & elem2 ){ ... }
        static bool sortbytype( const AC & elem1, const AC & elem2 ){ ... }
        static bool sortbyid  ( const AC & elem1, const AC & elem2 ){ ... }
}
```

And then using sort using the appropriate syntax for invoking static functions:

```
sort(iVec.begin(),iVec.end(),MyComparator::sortbysize);
```

If you really prefer to follow a regular comparable class style, you can do (although appears to be a bit stupid) things like using a static marker inside the class that specifies how the comparison operator will work:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int type;
    int id;

    enum marker { SIZE, TYPE, ID };
    static AC::marker comparisonType;

    bool operator() (const AC & i,const AC & j) 
    { 
        // Work here to make the enum thing work with the switch-case... 
        // it's all about integers
        switch(AC::comparisonType){
        case SIZE:
            return (i.size < j.size);
        ...
        }
    }
} AC;
```